# Replace/Ignore Special Characters in Text File, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, encoding

I am reading below content from text file, and I have used encoding='ISO-8859-1', still I can see special characters in my Dataframe. Please let me know the proper encoding for this.

```
'CaÃ±on City|Colorado|Canon City, CO', 
'Kapaâ\x80\x98a|Hawaii|Kapaa, HI', 
'Waiâ\x80\x98anae|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI',
'â\x80\x98ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI',
'â\x80\x98ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'â\x80\x98aiea|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'La CaÃ±ada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA', 
'La CaÃ±ada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA', 
'EspaÃ±ola|New Mexico|Espanola, NM', 
'EspaÃ±ola|New Mexico|Espanola, NM'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have ISO-8859-1 encoded text, and are reading it as Unicode.

If you know the encoding for sure, then you can decode it directly:

```
import codecs
lines = [ 
  'CaÃ±on City|Colorado|Canon City, CO', 
  'Kapaâ\x80\x98a|Hawaii|Kapaa, HI', 
  'Waiâ\x80\x98anae|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI',
  'â\x80\x98ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI',
  'â\x80\x98ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
  'â\x80\x98aiea|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
  'La CaÃ±ada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA', 
  'La CaÃ±ada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA', 
  'EspaÃ±ola|New Mexico|Espanola, NM', 
  'EspaÃ±ola|New Mexico|Espanola, NM' 
]
utf8_lines = [ 
  codecs.decode(bytes(line,'ISO-8859-1'), 'UTF-8')
  for line in lines 
]
```

utf8_lines

```
[ 
'Cañon City|Colorado|Canon City, CO', 
'Kapa‘a|Hawaii|Kapaa, HI', 
'Wai‘anae|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'‘ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'‘ewa Beach|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'‘aiea|Hawaii|Urban Honolulu, HI', 
'La Cañada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA', 
'La Cañada Flintridge|California|Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA',
'Española|New Mexico|Espanola, NM', 
'Española|New Mexico|Espanola, NM'
]
```

If you have unknown encodings, or even duplicate encodings within a single file, then the `ftfy` library will autodetect and fix all your encoding issues. It can be a little CPU intensive if using it inside a big data pipeline (only run it on segments of text containing non-ascii chars), but your encoding issues will be solved.

```
[ 
  ftfy.fix_encoding(line)
  for line in lines 
]
[ 
  ftfy.fix_text(line)
  for line in lines 
]
```

- https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/